# Where did my 15 points go?

Tags: support

I'm not particularly motivated by point-scoring, but I'm curious about what caused the -15 change on [Strength of a welded steel gate with vertical bars vs. crossed diagonal bars](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/strength-of-a-welded-steel-gate-with-vertical-bars-vs-crossed-diagonal-bars/3912#3912)

I can't see any down-votes, and the comments suggest my answer was useful.

Is there a tool that I don't know about which gives more details of point-scoring?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the OP of that question changed their selected answer to another answer.  Looking at your reputation, there is a -15 associated with an unaccept on that particular question.

You should be able to see that information on your reputation tab:

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/683/alephzero?tab=reputation

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there somewhere I can see that sort of information myself?